# How do I add in bound processing policy in APIM?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I am trying to add the following in bound processing policy to my APIM for an operation:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rewrite-uri template="/stores/{Location}/slots?StartDate={StartDateTime}&amp;AppointmentType={AppointmentType}" />
        <set-header name="ocp-apim-subscription-key" exists-action="override">
            <value>12d0bdd57ca84fa9ad35f13f22605dbf</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I have found this commandlet, however there is no information on what to put in `-Policy`.

I have tried using the following

```
    $policyString = '<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rewrite-uri template="/stores/{Location}/slots?StartDate={StartDateTime}&amp;AppointmentType={AppointmentType}" />
        <set-header name="ocp-apim-subscription-key" exists-action="override">
            <value>12d0bdd57ca84fa9ad35f13f22605dbf</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>'

Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy -Context $apiMgmtContext -ApiId $apiId -Policy $policyString -OperationId 'GetCalendar'
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
```

What format is the Policy param expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the format of `-Policy` parameter seems to be correct, the issue was caused by the `rewrite-uri` in your policy.

`<rewrite-uri template="/stores/{Location}/slots?StartDate={StartDateTime}&amp;AppointmentType={AppointmentType}" />`

[image]

I test it with the sample in the official doc, it works fine.

```
<rewrite-uri template="/put" />
```

[image]

For more details about the usage of `rewrite-uri`, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joy Wang for pointing me in the right direction, here's the solution:

I tried adding the XML directly through the portal, and got this error:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: Error in element
>   'rewrite-uri' on line 4, column 10: Only parameters specified in the
>   original URL template can be used in the rewrite template

Turns out the parameters I was referring to (`StartDateTime` and `AppointmentType`) were not part of the template params in the APIM.

Once I added them as template params in APIM, the command worked.

Would be good if the Powershell commandlet returned the same error as the Azure Portal, rather than just 'BadRequest'

Comment: Could you accept my reply as the answer? Anyway, I think my reply points out the error and corrects your direction.